# Access 2016: BeforeUpdate cancelled if button not pressed

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am working on a form where users can add records once they have filled all required fields. [Pic of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddedT.jpg) One of the field is named region and it is a combobox with all the regions in the database. The issue arises once the user tries to add a new region. In order to add a new region, the user presses the button "add new region" which opens another form. Once they are satisfied, they can save the region by exiting the form, which prompts saving and adds the region to the combobox. [Adding a new region prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4tqv.jpg)

Here are the macros in the button to save and close the form to add a new region:

**CloseWindow**
Object Type
Object Name
Save  Prompt

**RunMenuCommand**
Command  Refresh

Once the user presses the button, they are prompted with the message of exiting form without saving changes of F_saisie_2. This should not happen in reality since the user has not pressed the button in question named Btn_QuitSaisie. [What happens when going back to the main form after adding a new region if user has already filled some of the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACeuP.jpg) (changes are erased) (There is a button at the bottom which serves to save and go to new record automatically: I want to force the user to save their entry with it)

Here are the macro and code for the button Btn_QuitSaisie:

**RunMenuCommand**
Command  Close

```
Private Sub Btn_QuitSaisie_Click()
Dim intReponse As Integer
    intReponse = MsgBox("Vous vous apprêtez à quitter sans sauvegarder.", vbOKOnly, "Quitter formulaire") 'Translation: You are about to exit without saving. Exit form
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
End Sub
```

Now, for the button to work, I have also added this following code to the BeforeUpdate event;

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim intReponse As Integer
    intReponse = MsgBox("Vous vous apprêtez à quitter sans sauvegarder.", vbOKOnly, "Quitter formulaire")
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo


End Sub
```

This is problematic since it is applying everytime there is an update to the form (when adding a region for example).

I want to know if there is a way to prevent the procedure of the BeforeUpdate when the button Btn_QuitSaisie is not pressed.

As of right now, when adding a region, it prompts the message, undoes the user's changes in previous fields without leaving the form F_saisie_2.

I had two ideas to solve the problem.
Either cancelling the BeforeUpdate event if the button Btn_QuitSaisie is not pressed.
Or graying the fields which do not have to "add" new entries to a combobox to force the user to enter the region first and as such would not 'undo' anything since the user has not entered any information yet.

I believe the first idea would be the best of the two since it 'solves' the problem instead of going around it.

I have also tried to put the BeforeUpdate event in the Unload event instead but it did not work at all. Rather it still saved the changes when pressing the Btn_QuitSaisie.

Comment: Instead ``RunMenuCommand Command Refresh`` try ``comboBox.Requery``

Comment: How would you go about that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have two buttons on your form so that the user can decide which action to take. One to Save the region and one to Exit the form without saving. Both buttons should exit the form however the Exit button should confirm that the user does not want to add the region. I have made some assumptions in this answer that the form only allows additions, the form only allows the addition of one region, and that the table is bound to the form. You do not need to consider the BeforeUpdate event in this scenario unless of course you want to do some data entry checks.

Button to Exit without save:

```
Private Sub Btn_QuitSaisie_Click()   ' Exit without saving

    With Me
        If .Dirty = True Then
            If MsgBox("Vous vous apprêtez à quitter sans sauvegarder.", vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2, "Quitter formulaire") =vbOk Then 'Translation: You are about to exit without saving. Exit form
                .Undo
                DoCmd.Close acForm, .Name, acSaveNo
            End If
        Else
            ' No data changed. Exit without prompt.
            DoCmd.Close acForm, .Name, acSaveNo
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Button to exit normally with save:

```
Private Sub Btn_SaveRegion_Click()   ' Exit with save

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Comment: or: `acSaveYes`?

Comment: The code for the button works in the sense it does not prompt the user with exiting without saving and undoing the previous changes anymore. However, now it will still save the entry even if all fields are not complete instead of deleting it. The prompt will appear yet not undo.

Comment: @Gustav, acSaveYes and acSaveNo apply to the form object itself, not to the data that was entered by the user. For example, if you are programmatically changing the RowSource of a Combo Box, acSaveYes will save the form with the last RowSource that was applied by your code.

Comment: You will need to add code in the Btn_SaveRegion_Click() event to check the data validity and completeness and issue another message telling the user they have missing or invalid data. The checks need to be placed before DoCmd.Close. The message box should only have an Ok option. For example: `If Nz(TextBox1.Value) = "" Then   MsgBox "Textbox1 data is missing."   Exit Sub End If`

Comment: Why checking the data's validity and completeness in the Btn_SaveRegion_Click()? Would'nt it be in the Btn_QuitSaisie which closes the form? And can I still apply this logic of creating a MsgBox to signal to the user that there is data missing in the exit form button?

Comment: Why check data validity when the user has decided to exit without saving? The Msgbox in Btn_QuitSaisie only serves to make the user aware that they have unsaved changes. They can then choose to continue exiting without saving or they now realise that they have clicked the wrong button. The only place where data could be saved is in the Btn_SaveRegion_Click event and that is where the data check needs to happen. They will be unable to both save and exit until the checks pass.

Comment: Okay for creating a second option to go back to form and continue editing until all fields are valid. Would the code look something like this: ` Private Sub Btn_QuitSaisie_Click()     With Me    If .Dirty=True Then   If MsgBox ("Exiting without saving.", vbYesNo + vbdefaultButton2, "Exit Form") = vbYes Then 
   .Undo    DoCmd.Close acForm, .Name, acSaveNo 
  Else   (**code to go back to edit**)   End If 
   Else   DoCmd.Close acForm, .Name, acSaveNo 
  End If   End With   End Sub` However, I do not want to undo the region added if someone wants to exit without saving

Comment: You are over-complicating this. There is no need to provide any **code to go back to edit**.  If the user responds No to exit without saving then you just let the procedure end without closing the form and the data originally entered by the user will still be shown to them . The logic is shown in my original answer. Be aware that UnDo only applies to _changed_ form data. It will not impact any underlying data in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something which seems to work;

Instead of using the Btn_QuitSaisie and displaying a prompt to inform the user that the changes will not be saved I disabled Btn_QuitSaisie when fields are not empty.

Here is the code I ended up settling on.

```
Private Sub Btn_QuitSaisie_click()
DoCmd.close  'button only has the option to close
End Sub


Private Function ValidateFormExit() as Boolean
  if IsNull(Me.Nbr) Or IsNull(Me.Datepub) Or IsNull(Me.TitreContrat) _
    Or IsNull(Me.Region) Or IsNull(Me.Organisme) Or IsNull(Me.Classifications) _
    Or IsNull(Me.Adresse) Or IsNull(Me.Categories) Or IsNull(Me.Fournisseur) _
    Or IsNull(Me.NbrFournisseur) Then
    ValidateFormExit = True ' Enable button if all fields filled
Else
    ValidateFormExit = False ' Disable button if any field empty
End If
End Function


Private Sub Btn_delRec_Click() 'Deletes record and allows btn exit form
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
  Me.Btn_QuitSaisie.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

And then for each field I wanted to be empty before the close button could appear (displayed in the ValidateFormExit function), I added the following to the AfterUpdate event e.g. field Region.

```
Private Sub Region_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Btn_QuitSaisie.Enabled = Not ValidateFormExit()
End Sub
```

Thank you BobS and others for your help and input.